# Converting Python JSON File Into Pandas DataFrame

Tags: json, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe, etl

**I have the following Json file:**

```js
Json = json.loads(resp.text)
print pprint.pprint(Json)

Response:

{u'data': [{u'assignedUser': None,
            u'author': {u'authorData': {u'blogId': u'4050964395'},
                        u'authorFullName': None,
                        u'avatar': None,
                        u'bio': None,
                        u'comments': None,
                        u'externalId': u'2568086880',
                        u'externalLegacyId': None,
                        u'id': u'29011839',
                        u'influence': {u'score': 550},
                        u'socialNetworkTypeName': u'Twitter Profile Author',
                        u'tags': None,
                        u'title': None,
                        u'verified': None},
            u'classification': None,
            u'comments': [],
            u'content': None,
            u'engagement': None,
            u'entities': None,
            u'externalId': u'913186147185991680',
            u'externalLink': u'coms:stwittercomss2568086880sstatusess913186147185991680',
            u'firstEngagementDate': None,
            u'harvestDate': u'2017-09-27T23:38:50Z',
            u'id': u'688342654654',
            u'languageId': None,
            u'latestEngagementDate': None,
            u'mediaProvider': {u'extendedMediaType': None,
                               u'id': u'10',
                               u'mediaTypeId': 8,
                               u'title': u'TWITTER'},
            u'metadata': None,
            u'parent': {u'externalId': u'912930603221127168'},
            u'parentAuthor': {u'authorData': {u'blogId': u'6297935084'},
                              u'authorFullName': None,
                              u'avatar': None,
                              u'bio': None,
                              u'comments': None,
                              u'externalId': u'4861615638',
                              u'externalLegacyId': None,
                              u'id': u'330423308',
                              u'influence': None,
                              u'socialNetworkTypeName': None,
                              u'tags': None,
                              u'title': None,
                              u'verified': None},
            u'postDynamics': [],
            u'postStatus': 0,
            u'postStatusException': None,
            u'priority': None,
            u'publishedDate': u'2017-09-27T23:38:38Z',
            u'regionId': None,
            u'sentiment': [{u'overridden': False,
                            u'topicId': 1133213,
                            u'value': 0}],
            u'source': {u'comments': [],
                        u'externalLink': u'twittercoms',
                        u'id': u'4050964395',
                        u'language': None,
                        u'region': None,
                        u'tags': [],
                        u'title': None,
                        u'verified': None},
            u'sourceApplication': None,
            u'sourceFilterMatches': None,
            u'summaryContent': None,
            u'tags': [],
            u'title': None,
            u'topics': [1133213],
            u'workflowHistory': []},
           {u'assignedUser': None,
            u'author': {u'authorData': {u'blogId': u'4050964395'},
                        u'authorFullName': None,
                        u'avatar': None,
                        u'bio': None,
                        u'comments': None,
                        u'externalId': u'2568086880',
                        u'externalLegacyId': None,
                        u'id': u'29011839',
                        u'influence': {u'score': 550},
                        u'socialNetworkTypeName': u'Twitter Profile Author',
                        u'tags': None,
                        u'title': None,
                        u'verified': None},
            u'classification': None,
            u'comments': [],
            u'content': None,
            u'engagement': None,
            u'entities': {u'hashtags': None,
                          u'media': [{u'description': None,
                                      u'display_url': u'pictwittercomsstbK8mF4vHO',
                                      u'expanded_url': u'htptwittercomssigaitokamonesstatuss912684996690812928sphotos1',
                                      u'id': u'912684878763659264',
                                      u'indices': [27, 50],
                                      u'media_url': u'coms:spbstwimgcomssmediasDKqCD8aUEAAX9qzjpg',
                                      u'media_url_comss': u'htppbstwimgcomssmediasDKqCD8aUEAAX9qzjpg',
                                      u'target_url': None,
                                      u'title': None,
                                      u'type': u'photo',
                                      u'url': u'htptcostbK8mF4vHO',
                                      u'video_info': None},
                                     {u'description': None,
                                      u'display_url': u'pictwittercomsstbK8mF4vHO',
                                      u'expanded_url': u'htptwittercomssigaitokamonesstatuss912684996690812928sphotos1',
                                      u'id': u'912684910049058816',
                                      u'indices': [27, 50],
                                      u'media_url': u'coms:spbstwimgcomssmediasDKqCFw9VYAAYsOdjpg',
                                      u'media_url_comss': u'htppbstwimgcomssmediasDKqCFw9VYAAYsOdjpg',
                                      u'target_url': None,
                                      u'title': None,
                                      u'type': u'photo',
                                      u'url': u'htptcostbK8mF4vHO',
                                      u'video_info': None},
                                     {u'description': None,
                                      u'display_url': u'pictwittercomsstbK8mF4vHO',
                                      u'expanded_url': u'htptwittercomssigaitokamonesstatuss912684996690812928sphotos1',
                                      u'id': u'912684937341394944',
                                      u'indices': [27, 50],
                                      u'media_url': u'coms:spbstwimgcomssmediasDKqCHWoVYAAqqMAjpg',
                                      u'media_url_comss': u'htppbstwimgcomssmediasDKqCHWoVYAAqqMAjpg',
                                      u'target_url': None,
                                      u'title': None,
                                      u'type': u'photo',
                                      u'url': u'htptcostbK8mF4vHO',
                                      u'video_info': None},
                                     {u'description': None,
                                      u'display_url': u'pictwittercomsstbK8mF4vHO',
                                      u'expanded_url': u'htptwittercomssigaitokamonesstatuss912684996690812928sphotos1',
                                      u'id': u'912684966760161281',
                                      u'indices': [27, 50],
                                      u'media_url': u'coms:spbstwimgcomssmediasDKqCJEOUIAEnVD-jpg',
                                      u'media_url_comss': u'htppbstwimgcomssmediasDKqCJEOUIAEnVD-jpg',
                                      u'target_url': None,
                                      u'title': None,
                                      u'type': u'photo',
                                      u'url': u'htptcostbK8mF4vHO',
                                      u'video_info': None}],
                          u'mentions': None,
                          u'urls': None},
            u'externalId': u'913185982639304704',
            u'externalLink': u'coms:stwittercomss2568086880sstatusess913185982639304704',
            u'firstEngagementDate': None,
            u'harvestDate': u'2017-09-27T23:38:11Z',
            u'id': u'688342490373',
            u'languageId': None,
            u'latestEngagementDate': None,
            u'mediaProvider': {u'extendedMediaType': None,
                               u'id': u'10',
                               u'mediaTypeId': 8,
                               u'title': u'TWITTER'},
            u'metadata': None,
            u'parent': {u'externalId': u'912684996690812928'},
            u'parentAuthor': {u'authorData': {u'blogId': u'237430348'},
                              u'authorFullName': None,
                              u'avatar': None,
                              u'bio': None,
                              u'comments': None,
                              u'externalId': u'2689515817',
                              u'externalLegacyId': None,
                              u'id': u'112855989',
                              u'influence': None,
                              u'socialNetworkTypeName': None,
                              u'tags': None,
                              u'title': None,
                              u'verified': None},
            u'postDynamics': [],
            u'postStatus': 0,
            u'postStatusException': None,
            u'priority': None,
            u'publishedDate': u'2017-09-27T23:37:59Z',
            u'regionId': None,
            u'sentiment': [{u'overridden': False,
                            u'topicId': 1133213,
                            u'value': 0}],
            u'source': {u'comments': [],
                        u'externalLink': u'twittercoms',
                        u'id': u'4050964395',
                        u'language': None,
                        u'region': None,
                        u'tags': [],
                        u'title': None,
                        u'verified': None},
            u'sourceApplication': None,
            u'sourceFilterMatches': None,
            u'summaryContent': None,
            u'tags': [],
            u'title': None,
            u'topics': [1133213],
            u'workflowHistory': []},
           {u'assignedUser': None,
            u'author': {u'authorFullName': u'Harry M',
                        u'avatar': None,
                        u'bio': None,
                        u'comments': None,
                        u'externalId': u'-1',
                        u'externalLegacyId': None,
                        u'id': u'-1',
                        u'socialNetworkTypeName': None,
                        u'tags': None,
                        u'title': u'Harry M',
                        u'verified': False},
            u'classification': None,
            u'comments': [],
            u'content': u"we'll have to wait and see if this one is vapourware, like the FF91",
            u'engagement': None,
            u'entities': None,
            u'externalId': u'z22osbpbsvj3hd1euacdp43aqlqerg0o1gv1t14dom1w03c010c',
            u'externalLink': u'coms:swwwyoutubecomsswatch?v=ePJ8xcL3HAE#z22osbpbsvj3hd1euacdp43aqlqerg0o1gv1t14dom1w03c010c',
            u'firstEngagementDate': None,
            u'harvestDate': u'2017-09-27T23:17:17Z',
            u'id': u'688337451911',
            u'languageId': 1,
            u'latestEngagementDate': None,
            u'mediaProvider': {u'extendedMediaType': None,
                               u'id': u'777',
                               u'mediaTypeId': 11,
                               u'title': u'YouTube Comments'},
            u'metadata': None,
            u'parent': {u'externalId': u'ePJ8xcL3HAE',
                        u'id': u'655094359463'},
            u'postDynamics': [],
            u'postStatus': 0,
            u'postStatusException': None,
            u'priority': None,
            u'publishedDate': u'2017-09-27T22:22:21Z',
            u'regionId': 249,
            u'sentiment': [{u'overridden': False,
                            u'topicId': 1133213,
                            u'value': 0}],
            u'source': {u'comments': [],
                        u'externalLink': u'youtubecoms',
                        u'id': u'5631651605',
                        u'language': u'en',
                        u'region': None,
                        u'tags': [],
                        u'title': u'Harry M on Lucid Air (2019) Tesla Model S killer [YOUCAR] '},
            u'sourceApplication': None,
            u'sourceFilterMatches': None,
            u'summaryContent': None,
            u'tags': [],
            u'title': u'Harry M on Lucid Air (2019) Tesla Model S killer [YOUCAR] ',
            u'topics': [1133213],
            u'workflowHistory': []},
           {u'assignedUser': None,
            u'author': {u'authorFullName': u'Bruce Magnus',
                        u'avatar': None,
                        u'bio': None,
                        u'comments': None,
                        u'externalId': u'-1',
                        u'externalLegacyId': None,
                        u'id': u'-1',
                        u'socialNetworkTypeName': None,
                        u'tags': None,
                        u'title': u'Bruce Magnus',
                        u'verified': False},
            u'classification': None,
            u'comments': [],
            u'content': u'Faraday Future has just released their debut 2018 FF91 at CES 2017 It is very much still in its beta phase with a lot of promises One of those is that the car can achieve 0 -60MPH in 239 seconds How does it feel to sit in a car with such a massive amount of power?',
            u'engagement': None,
            u'entities': None,
            u'externalId': u'cFcYnSDRBMs',
            u'externalLink': u'coms:swwwyoutubecomsswatch?v=cFcYnSDRBMs',
            u'firstEngagementDate': None,
            u'harvestDate': u'2017-09-27T21:28:19Z',
            u'id': u'688311663482',
            u'languageId': 1,
            u'latestEngagementDate': None,
            u'mediaProvider': {u'extendedMediaType': None,
                               u'id': u'2',
                               u'mediaTypeId': 2,
                               u'title': u'YouTube'},
            u'metadata': None,
            u'parent': None,
            u'postDynamics': [{u'label': u'View Count', u'value': u'2'},
                              {u'label': u'Comment Count', u'value': u'0'},
                              {u'label': u'Unique Commenters',
                               u'value': u'0'},
                              {u'label': u'Engagement', u'value': u'0'},
                              {u'label': u'Likes and Votes',
                               u'value': u'0'},
                              {u'label': u'Inbound Links', u'value': u'0'}],
            u'postStatus': 0,
            u'postStatusException': None,
            u'priority': None,
            u'publishedDate': u'2017-09-27T03:09:07Z',
            u'regionId': 249,
            u'sentiment': [{u'overridden': False,
                            u'topicId': 1133213,
                            u'value': 10}],
            u'source': {u'comments': [],
                        u'externalLink': u'youtubecoms',
                        u'id': u'7186804057',
                        u'language': u'en',
                        u'region': None,
                        u'tags': [],
                        u'title': u'FF91 Faraday Future - TESTING 0 - 60 MPH IN 24 SECONDS'},
            u'sourceApplication': None,
            u'sourceFilterMatches': None,
            u'summaryContent': None,
            u'tags': [],
            u'title': u'FF91 Faraday Future - TESTING 0 - 60 MPH IN 24 SECONDS',
            u'topics': [1133213],
            u'workflowHistory': []},
           {u'assignedUser': None,
            u'author': {u'authorData': {u'blogId': u'4502740665'},
                        u'authorFullName': None,
                        u'avatar': None,
                        u'bio': None,
                        u'comments': None,
                        u'externalId': u'2788814143',
                        u'externalLegacyId': None,
                        u'id': u'30430561',
                        u'influence': {u'score': 80},
                        u'socialNetworkTypeName': u'Twitter Profile Author',
                        u'tags': None,
                        u'title': None,
                        u'verified': None},
            u'classification': None,
            u'comments': [],
            u'content': None,
            u'engagement': None,
            u'entities': {u'hashtags': None,
                          u'media': [{u'description': None,
                                      u'display_url': u'pictwittercomsstGHUZ2ncMU',
                                      u'expanded_url': u'htptwittercomssAllstonAutosstatuss913103968300969984sphotos1',
                                      u'id': u'913103966023462912',
                                      u'indices': [100, 123],
                                      u'media_url': u'coms:spbstwimgcomssmediasDKv_OCHUMAA-QHSjpg',
                                      u'media_url_comss': u'htppbstwimgcomssmediasDKv_OCHUMAA-QHSjpg',
                                      u'target_url': None,
                                      u'title': None,
                                      u'type': u'photo',
                                      u'url': u'htptcostGHUZ2ncMU',
                                      u'video_info': None}],
                          u'mentions': None,
                          u'urls': [{u'display_url': u'dlvritsPqs7xk',
                                     u'expanded_url': u'coms:sdlvritsPqs7xk',
                                     u'indices': [76, 99],
                                     u'url': u'htptcosM2xcaQ5Os0'}]},
            u'externalId': u'913103968300969984',
            u'externalLink': u'coms:stwittercomss2788814143sstatusess913103968300969984',
            u'firstEngagementDate': None,
            u'harvestDate': u'2017-09-27T18:12:11Z',
            u'id': u'688263442101',
            u'languageId': None,
            u'latestEngagementDate': None,
            u'mediaProvider': {u'extendedMediaType': None,
                               u'id': u'10',
                               u'mediaTypeId': 8,
                               u'title': u'TWITTER'},
            u'metadata': None,
            u'parent': None,
            u'postDynamics': [],
            u'postStatus': 0,
            u'postStatusException': None,
            u'priority': None,
            u'publishedDate': u'2017-09-27T18:12:05Z',
            u'regionId': None,
            u'sentiment': [{u'overridden': False,
                            u'topicId': 1133213,
                            u'value': -10}],
            u'source': {u'comments': [],
                        u'externalLink': u'twittercoms',
                        u'id': u'4502740665',
                        u'language': None,
                        u'region': None,
                        u'tags': [],
                        u'title': None,
                        u'verified': None},
            u'sourceApplication': None,
            u'sourceFilterMatches': None,
            u'summaryContent': None,
            u'tags': [],
            u'title': None,
            u'topics': [1133213],
            u'workflowHistory': []},
           {u'assignedUser': None,
            u'author': {u'authorData': {u'blogId': u'6202921586'},
                        u'authorFullName': None,
                        u'avatar': None,
                        u'bio': None,
                        u'comments': None,
                        u'externalId': u'2669983818',
                        u'externalLegacyId': None,
                        u'id': u'314584800',
                        u'influence': {u'score': 500},
                        u'socialNetworkTypeName': u'Twitter Profile Author',
                        u'tags': None,
                        u'title': None,
                        u'verified': None},
            u'classification': None,
            u'comments': [],
            u'content': None,
            u'engagement': None,
            u'entities': None,
            u'externalId': u'913089957010350080',
            u'externalLink': u'coms:stwittercomss2669983818sstatusess913089957010350080',
            u'firstEngagementDate': None,
            u'harvestDate': u'2017-09-27T17:16:32Z',
            u'id': u'688249615145',
            u'languageId': None,
            u'latestEngagementDate': None,
            u'mediaProvider': {u'extendedMediaType': None,
                               u'id': u'10',
                               u'mediaTypeId': 8,
                               u'title': u'TWITTER'},
            u'metadata': None,
            u'parent': None,
            u'postDynamics': [],
            u'postStatus': 0,
            u'postStatusException': None,
            u'priority': None,
            u'publishedDate': u'2017-09-27T17:16:24Z',
            u'regionId': None,
            u'sentiment': [{u'overridden': False,
                            u'topicId': 1133213,
                            u'value': 0}],
            u'source': {u'comments': [],
                        u'externalLink': u'twittercoms',
                        u'id': u'6202921586',
                        u'language': None,
                        u'region': None,
                        u'tags': [],
                        u'title': None,
                        u'verified': None},
            u'sourceApplication': None,
            u'sourceFilterMatches': None,
            u'summaryContent': None,
            u'tags': [],
            u'title': None,
            u'topics': [1133213],
            u'workflowHistory': []},
           {u'assignedUser': None,
            u'author': {u'authorData': {u'blogId': u'2987515632'},
                        u'authorFullName': None,
                        u'avatar': None,
                        u'bio': None,
                        u'comments': None,
                        u'externalId': u'2169387900',
                        u'externalLegacyId': None,
                        u'id': u'46147122',
                        u'influence': {u'score': 170},
                        u'socialNetworkTypeName': u'Twitter Profile Author',
                        u'tags': None,
                        u'title': None,
                        u'verified': None},
            u'classification': None,
            u'comments': [],
            u'content': None,
            u'engagement': None,
            u'entities': {u'hashtags': None,
                          u'media': None,
                          u'mentions': [{u'id': u'10228272',
                                         u'indices': [116, 124],
                                         u'name': u'YouTube',
                                         u'screen_name': u'YouTube',
                                         u'url': None}],
                          u'urls': [{u'display_url': u'youtubesb6QrF59zLQU?a',
                                     u'expanded_url': u'coms:syoutubesb6QrF59zLQU?a',
                                     u'indices': [88, 111],
                                     u'url': u'htptcosEGPB3xjmSm'}]},
            u'externalId': u'913089735249268736',
            u'externalLink': u'coms:stwittercomss2169387900sstatusess913089735249268736',
            u'firstEngagementDate': None,
            u'harvestDate': u'2017-09-27T17:15:41Z',
            u'id': u'688249356612',
            u'languageId': None,
            u'latestEngagementDate': None,
            u'mediaProvider': {u'extendedMediaType': None,
                               u'id': u'10',
                               u'mediaTypeId': 8,
                               u'title': u'TWITTER'},
            u'metadata': None,
            u'parent': None,
            u'postDynamics': [],
            u'postStatus': 0,
            u'postStatusException': None,
            u'priority': None,
            u'publishedDate': u'2017-09-27T17:15:31Z',
            u'regionId': None,
            u'sentiment': [{u'overridden': False,
                            u'topicId': 1133213,
                            u'value': -10}],
            u'source': {u'comments': [],
                        u'externalLink': u'twittercoms',
                        u'id': u'2987515632',
                        u'language': None,
                        u'region': None,
                        u'tags': [],
                        u'title': None,
                        u'verified': None},
            u'sourceApplication': None,
            u'sourceFilterMatches': None,
            u'summaryContent': None,
            u'tags': [],
            u'title': None,
            u'topics': [1133213],
            u'workflowHistory': []}],
 u'meta': {u'totalCount': 251}}
None
```

**I need to convert the elements in data['postDynamics'] into a pandas data frame. As you can see I cannot just do a loop for each label and it's corresponding value as some of the line items have empty lists. I want to be able to extract everything into a pandas data frame, sequentially. This is where i'm stuck!**

```js
for data in Json['data']:
    print data['postDynamics']

Response:

[]
[]
[]
[{u'value': u'2', u'label': u'View Count'}, {u'value': u'0', u'label': u'Comment Count'}, {u'value': u'0', u'label': u'Unique Commenters'}, {u'value': u'0', u'label': u'Engagement'}, {u'value': u'0', u'label': u'Likes and Votes'}, {u'value': u'0', u'label': u'Inbound Links'}]
[]
[]
[]
```

**Ideally i'd like to put the data into a pandas data frame and write into a csv file that looks like this:**

[image]

**I would appreciate anyone's help.**

Comment: No images please . How can we copy the data to come with a solution. Please post the text version before you get downvotes.

Comment: I'm sorry, i'm new to this platform, Let me fix it right now.

Comment: Can you change the down votes please? I inserted the code.

Comment: I din't downvote. I usually wont downvote

Answer (score 0):

Use pandas native methods:

```
pd.read_json(Json)
```

Comment: I get this error:

ValueError: Invalid file path or buffer object type: <type 'dict'>

Comment: Which means your datatype hasn't been converted to a json. `pd.from_dict(Json)` is your alternative option

Comment: I get this error: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'from_dict'
I did convert it into a json file per my code above.

Comment: Your error suggests you don't have pandas imported. `import pandas as pd`

Comment: Also check `type(Json)`

Comment: i imported pandas as pd, i don't think that's the error. Also, i executed type(Json) and it returned: dict

Comment: I also just tried this: 'pd.DataFrame.from_dict(Json)' and i got this error: ValueError: Mixing dicts with non-Series may lead to ambiguous ordering.

Comment: Now that we've established you're using a dictionary, `pd.DataFrame(Json)` is an alternative way to go from dictionary to dataframe

Comment: When i execute **pd.DataFrame(Json)** I get the following error: ValueError: Mixing dicts with non-Series may lead to ambiguous ordering.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33559660/error-while-reading-json-file

Comment: While this helps, it still does not answer my original question on how to unpack the nested lists in **data['postDynamics']**